# How can I parse this xml?

Tags: xml, parsing, soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <PaymentNotification xmlns="http://apilistener.envoyservices.com">
      <payment>
        <uniqueReference>ESDEUR11039872</uniqueReference>      
        <epacsReference>74348dc0-cbf0-df11-b725-001ec9e61285</epacsReference>
        <postingDate>2010-11-15T15:19:45</postingDate>
        <bankCurrency>EUR</bankCurrency>
        <bankAmount>1.00</bankAmount>
        <appliedCurrency>EUR</appliedCurrency>
        <appliedAmount>1.00</appliedAmount>
        <countryCode>ES</countryCode>
        <bankInformation>Sean Wood</bankInformation>
  <merchantReference>ESDEUR11039872</merchantReference>
   </payment>
    </PaymentNotification>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?  (Do you need everything that's in the XML?)  What language are you using? ...

Comment: php, 'uniqueReference' for example

Comment: I have parsed a lot of xml with 1 root , but it's SOAP xml. Please help.

Comment: SOAP XML only has one root too

Comment: yes, could you advise how to parse it,  with small example.  I tried: $xml = simplexml_load_string($soap_response);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//payment') as $item)
{
    print_r($item);
}

Answer (score 2):

With an XML parser.

How are you getting this XML?

Comment: If you are getting this information from a SOAP service, you should be using a SOAP library already written in PHP. Generally, you *don't* want to parse a SOAP response yourself, that should be handled by the *same* code which sends the request for you.

Comment: So....Not clear how to parse via SOAP library. I have XML SOAP response , i need to parse it (SimpleXML, SAX, etc).

Comment: You **don't** parse the response. If you are using a SOAP library, the library will convert the response back into a PHP object for you

Comment: How are you getting that data from the Envoy server? What request are you making?

Comment: I do some actions in admin panel, an it send me Payment Notifications

Comment: from spec. 2.2.1 Purpose of the Listener
A listener would be expected to do the following processes:
 Accept an HTTP Post containing this XML message shown above
 Parse the fields enclosed in the payment element
 Store the fields, as is relevant to the merchant’s own system
 Respond to the HTTP Post with the text ‘SUCCESS’ if the merchant is happy with the contents of
the message or ‘ERROR <description of error>’ if they are not.

Comment: Ok, sounds like they are misusing SOAP in a stupid way. However this is normal XML - There's no reason that your normal method won't work. Either update this question or start a new one, showing what you're trying and where you're getting something different to what you expect

Answer (score 2):

With your favorite XML parser, of course.

You don't say which language you'll write the consumer in.  Java has built-in XML parsers or you can try the Apache Xerces parser.

Python has an XML parser as well.  So do all languages these days.